# How to do preprocessing inside a Keras model for new inference-only end-to-end model

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras, tensorflow-serving

With Tensorflow 2.3, I've trained a tf.keras model with EfficientNet and now I want to export an inference-only end-to-end model that will include the preprocessing layers (essentially decoding an image encoded as a base64 string and potentially processing the normalization). My code to define the trained model and the inference model:

```
imageSize = (224,224,3)
inputs = layers.Input(shape=imageSize)
eff_net_model = EfficientNetB0(input_tensor=inputs)
eff_net_model.compile(...)
eff_net_model.fit(...)
# training is finished now wrap the model with preprocessing for inference model
model = b64_image_model_wrapper(eff_net_model,imageSize)
```

My wrapper fct is the following:

```
def b64_image_model_wrapper(model,imageSize,method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.BILINEAR, 
                        mean=0.0,std=1.0,input_name="b64_image"):

  def preprocess_and_decode(img_str, new_shape=imageSize):
    img = tf.io.decode_base64(img_str)
    img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
    img = tf.image.resize(img, new_shape, method=method)
    return img

  input64 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,), dtype="string", name=input_name)
  output_tensor = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(
    lambda img: tf.map_fn(lambda im: preprocess_and_decode(im[0]), img, fn_output_signature=tf.float32,swap_memory=True))(input64)
  x = (output_tensor - mean) / std
  x = model(x)
  new_model = tf.keras.Model(input64, x, name=model.name)
  new_model.output_names = model.output_names
  return new_model
```

Later if I want to predict with this new model (the one that takes as input a string encoded image) I do:

```
model.predict(np.array(["hello"])) # just for testing purposes
```

I get the error:

```
Exception has occurred: InvalidArgumentError
Expected image (JPEG, PNG, or GIF), got unknown format starting with '\261\330_\201\250\354\205\327\340i\327'
 [[{{node EfficientNet/lambda/map/while/body/_1/EfficientNet/lambda/map/while/DecodeJpeg}}]]
```

Likewise if I save this new model (`tf.saved_model.save(model)`) and try to use it with Tensorflow Serving I get the error:

```
Error while reading resource variable block6c_bn/moving_mean from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/block6c_bn/moving_mean)\n\t [[{{node functional_1/EfficientNet/block6c_bn/FusedBatchNormV3/ReadVariableOp}}]]
```

I don't know what it means exactly but it seems that some weights are not initialized? Am I doing the model wrapping the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get error when you call the `model.predict(np.array(["hello"]))` is because:

1. The input format is not base64 string
2. your input after `tf.io.decode_base64` is not `.jpg` file

Following code show you how to test the model using `.jpg` file:

```
with open("./homersimpson.0.0.jpg", "rb") as imageFile:
    base64_bytes = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(imageFile.read())
base64_strings = base64_bytes.decode('ascii')
img = tf.io.decode_base64(base64_strings)
prediction = model.predict(np.array([base64_strings]))
```

Also I using `model.save('./test_save_model')` to save the entire model which don't have any problem

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have accepted your answer as you were right about the first part (the problem was that my test string was not really an image). Unfortunately the second problem (which is apparently a different problem) still remains. When I save the model (your way or my way) and I try to serve it with Tensorflow Serving, I get an error like the one above ("Error while reading resource variable batch_normalization/gamma from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist"). If you have any hint...

Comment: That's why I was asking "am I doing right when I wrap the efficient net model" because it seems that the resulting wrapped model has some "uninitialized" parts

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think the information is enough for me to find the root cause of the second error when serving the model, can you serving the native EfficientNetB0 without any error? if so then the problem is likely in the wrap function you defined